# Eclipse IDE horizontal lines in Editor

Tags: eclipse

I'm using Eclipse 4.18 on Windows 10. The editor constantly shows horizontal lines at seemly random locations in the editor  - see picture link for an example: ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WqKi.png)). When scrolling up/down or when changing tabs those lines disappear (or get garbled) just to appear when scrolling again. It looks like a random pattern and I haven't been able to find anything in the Eclipse preferences to disable displaying the lines.

Previous versions of Eclipse had the same issue. Any ideas much appreciated.

Edit:
The first image ([1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6WqKi.png)) is taken from the sample Syntax Coloring option in Preferences -> XML > XML Files > Editor > Syntax Coloring which also displays the issue in a sample textbox.

Also, I include a screenshot of a sample .txt file opened in Eclipse IDE 2020-12 (4.18.0) (menu File -> Open File...) which shows the horizontal lines ([2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lRVjP.png)) on a new workspace with no plugins installed.
I hadn't encountered any similar issue on previous Eclipse versions on Win10 (I last used Eclipse in ~2019)

Comment: In which editors and views do you exactly observe this? Are there other Windows applications with this issue? Is this a fresh installation without additional plugins? If not, can you reproduce this with a fresh Eclipse without additional plugins?

Comment: It happens within the included IDE editor that comes with Eclipse. Those lines even appear with .txt files. No other Windows application shows such an issue - just Eclipse. It is a fresh installation with no additional plug-ins.

Comment: There are several editors included in Eclipse and I guess, you mean a specific (which?) Eclipse 2020-12 (4.18) IDE package, and not the Eclipse 4.18 SDK, since the cropped screenshot looks like an XML editor. Can you reproduce it with a fresh workspace? I have not seen this on any of my numerous different Eclipse installations on Windows 10. Please show a screenshot of the whole window.

Comment: Original post edited to provide more information and screenshot link included with a sample text file.

Comment: Strange. Maybe something with the font. Does in _Window > Preferences: General > Appearance > Colors and Fonts_ choosing a different _Basic > Text Font_ change something?

Comment: Very strange. Changing Text Font option seems to have solved the issue. I'll keep an eye on it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue exactly.
It started after replacing my monitor.
I have a monitor that require me to increase the DPI so I will see larger fonts especially in eclipse.

When you play around with your windows DPI setting you also need to change the DPI setting in eclipse so it will try to match especially if you have high resolution.

To tweak Eclipse DPI to try to match Windows DPI you need to edit (eclipse.ini) file. It should be on the same folder where eclipse.exe is located.
I had my setting on (-Dswt.autoScale = 175) when I see the lines you describe.
After changing it to 150 it was fixed .

Play around with Eclipse DPI setting I believe it would solve your problem. It did in my case. (maybe also Windows DPI but start first with Eclipse DPI settings)

After changing DPI setting in eclipse.ini you will need to restart eclipse to see the changes.

```
#eclipse.ini

-Dswt.enable.autoScale=true
-Dswt.autoScale=150
-Dswt.autoScale.method=nearest
```

[image]